# Symfony2 : remember me cookie gets deleted when reopening the browser

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

Despite of all the other questions on stack-overflow I was not able to resolve the issue with all the provided information.
That's why I decided to create a new one.

So I am implementing the remember me function in my login form with a checkbox that looks the like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="form_saveCredentials" name="form[saveCredentials]">
```

On login everything looks fine and the cookie gets set correctly

[image: cookie gets set correctly]

Through the whole browser session the cookie remains alive.
But when I close the browser and reopen it the cookie is still there (did not navigate to my localhost yet!).

When I navigate to my website on localhost the cookie gets deleted according to the response header

[image]

I have no idea why the cookie gets deleted on the navigation to the website.

Maybe the problem lies in the securtiy.yml settings for the remember_me functionality

```
firewalls:
    somefirewall:
        form_login:
            remember_me: true
remember_me:
        key: %secret%
        lifetime: 31536000
        remember_me_parameter: 'form[saveCredentials]'
        path: /
        domain: ~
```

Any idea on how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also finding the error, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I did not find a solution for the project i was currently working on. Though the problem disappeared when i used the remember me funtionalitie in a new project. In that project I extended the fosuserbundle instead of overriding it. I guess that solved it, nog sure though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently had this problem, and here is the solution I found:

The reason why the cookie is deleted is because the user information that the cookie contains doesn't match anything that Symfony knows about. It can't log a user in based on the cookie, so it just deletes it. The issue in my case was an incorrect string in my UserProvider class. The specific method is `supportsClass`. It was returning `'AppBundle\Security\User'` when it should have actually been returning `'AppBundle\Entity\User'. This caused Symfony to be unable to find any users based on the information in the cookie, and then it would just delete the cookie and move on.

You can do some more troubleshooting if you go into this file: `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.php`. Play around in `processAutoLoginCookie` and see if you can't figure something out!

Good luck!

Comment: This answer should be accepted. I had the same problem but not for exactly the same reason, but the same method (`TokenBasedRememberMeServices::processAutoLoginCookie`) was involved. In my case, I use the email and not the username to authenticate users. Even if you specify that the default provider should use another field than `username`, the remember me service will still store the username into the cookie. You have to wrote your own user provider exactly in the way described here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but was my fault: in LoginFormAuthenticator::onAuthenticationSuccess() I did not return RedirectResponse

```
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    // my error : new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('my_route_to_page'));

    return  new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('my_route_to_page'));
    
    //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
}
```

Once changed, I can login with username or email and the browser remember the cookie when I reopen again.

Answer (score -2):

This problem can occur if your username is a valid e-mail but isn't equal to the e-mail. Remove any @ in usernames.